# Why these char arrays seem to be out of bounds? (Linux System Programming example / C / readv)

Tags: c, linux

This example is taken from the [Linux System Programming](http://books.google.com/books?id=k_ocKY0iegsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Linux%20System%20Programming&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=tyGbTYPaDsyhOpC87a8H&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) book, page 88.

Code: http://pastebin.com/mEfmHbPP

The referenced text file 'buccaneer.txt' has such contents:

`The term buccaneer comes from the word boucan.
A boucan is a wooden frame used for cooking meat.
Buccaneer is the West Indies name for a pirate.`

The output of this program should be 3 such lines:

`0: The term buccaneer comes from the word boucan.
1: A boucan is a wooden frame used for cooking meat.
2: Buccaneer is the West Indies name for a pirate.`

But something strange happens on my machine and such output is displayed:

`0: The term buccaneer comes from the word boucan.
1: A boucan is a wooden frame used for cooking meat.
Buccaneer is the West Indies name for a pirate.
The term buccaneer comes from the word boucan.
2: Buccaneer is the West Indies name for a pirate.
The term buccaneer comes from the word boucan.`

when testing this I see that arrays **foo**, **bar** and **baz** report proper sizeof() values, the **iovcnt** equals 3 and the **nr** value returned by readv is 145 which is consistent with the file size reported by my system.
When I try to print contents of each array, the still report correct sizeof() BUT the contain WAY more characters. From the last listing: 
1st line - contents of foo,
lines 2,3,4 - contents of bar,
lines 5,6 - contents of baz.

I'm not new to C but I haven't run into such problem yet. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no null terminator on each string - so, sizeof will be OK, but your variables themselves will not be.  Either add a null terminator to each string or use the following formatting string for your printf:

```
"%x.xs"
```

(replace X with the sizeof value for the string)

Comment: No need to repeat the `x` twice. `%.xs` expresses the intent better. And you can avoid having to write the length out in the format string and make it programmatic by changing this to: `"%.*s", (int)sizeof str, str)`...

Comment: I suspected the null terminator might be a problem here. I thought it's added automatically though... apparently this is not the case. Thank you for your answers. EDIT: this example was copied from the book, on other linux systems the null terminator has to be added automatically I suspect...

Comment: I tried, but I've got only one point of rep... I need 15 to do that. When I gather 15 pts I'll upvote your answer.